# Can't get right autofill on specific case number

Tags: excel, excel-2013

I have a column with specific case numbers, which look like 1/2017, 2/2017, etc. The series can go until infinite (I don't know for sure how many cases I will have), but it would be nice to be able to use autofill. If I select the first 3 values and drag down the fill handle, I get 1/2018, 2/2018, 3/2018. I would need exactly the opposite, to linearly change the first number and leave 2017 alone. The formatting of the column is General. Should I create a custom formatting and/or block the changing of the 2017 somehow? (I know that you can block a value of a cell from changing with the *$* operator)

Thanks.

Comment: Go to Fill > Series... > Type [Cronological], Unit[Month], Increment: 1

Comment: Put 1 in a cell and 2 in an adjacent cell. Use a custom number format of `0\/\2\0\1\7` (which excel will auto-repair to `0\/2\017`). Fill as necessary.

Comment: @FernandoJ.Rivera I don't have Type [Cronological] available. Are you using 2013 Excel?

Comment: @MaXiMkA No, I'm using 2016, but I think this option has always been available. Sorry my screenshot is in spanish https://i.stack.imgur.com/c4599.png

Comment: By the way, you can read more here https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Create-a-list-of-sequential-dates-aa1c0fa7-c76a-4762-8bc9-46f1691defec

Comment: @Jeeped I created a custom number format, pulled down the Fill Handle, and the same result as before...

Comment: @Jeeped EDIT: Okay, nvm, for some odd reason Excel didn't refresh the values in the cells after applying the new format. My format code is: ##"/2017  ", the 2 spaces at the end are only for visual purposes. Thanks a lot, it works ^_^

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put 1 in a cell and 2 in an adjacent cell. Use a custom number format of 0/\2\0\1\7 (which excel will auto-repair to 0/2\017). Fill as necessary.

[image]

Remember that you are now looking for 1, 2, etc in VLOOKUP's or any other cell comparison or matching.